# Server Error (500) Django

Tags: python, django

Hola tengo este error al abrir el sitio que desarollo en Django, este es mi settings.py:

```
SECRET_KEY = '$+(+t#5=etj8+=osa$0v%ouzw%04piwfo!3%b8mli24!s$u6#j'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    'grappelli',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django_csv_exports',


    'apps.TipoBodegasapp',
    'apps.Pedidoapp',
    'bodega.settings',
    'apps',

]

GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = 'Grocer'


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bodega.urls'


TEMPLATES=  [

    {

        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bodega.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'Bodega',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'demaro',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-MX'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DJANGO_EXPORTS_REQUIRE_PERM = True 

import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(__file__).split(os.sep)[:-2] + ['static'])
STATICFILES_STORAGE ='django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Hola Demaro, fijate en la consola cual es el error que te arroja, pero por lo que estoy viendo estas importando la librería `os` después de haberla referenciado en la línea `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`, yo te diría de ponerla arriba de todo en el archivo y nos digas como te fue!

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

¿has probado a utilizar `debug = True` mientras te encuentras en el entorno de desarrollo? Así podrás ver más claramente el error que aparece.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Hola @Andruten, bienvenido a SOes, ayuda en refinar la pregunta con más datos útiles es bueno, pero mejor para comentarios, no para respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aviso @StefanNolde! Lo siento. Es que todavía no tengo la reputación suficiente para comentar u_u.

Comment: Eso es la idea. El concepto de SO no tiene el mismo sistema de revisión para comentarios que para respuestas y preguntas, así se espera que los usuarios se ganan el privilegio de hacer comentarios en publicaciones de otros haciendo buenas preguntas y dar respuestas útiles. Pruebalo, no es difícil de llegar a la reputación necesaria.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Concuerdo con @Andruten que esta es la respuesta correcta, porque en la configuración que tiene Debug esta seteado en False, por lo que ante cualquier problema Django mostrara un codigo 500 error en el servidor en ves de levantar y mostrar la vista de depuración para mostrar el error y asi poder informarse que es exactamente lo que lo esta causando.

Answer (score 0):

En las INSTALLED_APPS checa que 'django.contrib.admin' y'django_csv_exports', tenga 4 espacios de tabulacion al parecer solo tienes 3

Answer (score 0):

este error suele aparecer cuando no hay una recoleccion correcta de los staticfiles. Para esto debes correr el comando:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```